# Checking to see whether a document can be deleted

Tags: java, optimization

My code looks like this:

```
public void checkIfCanDelete() throws BusinessException {

    boolean canDelete = canDelete();

    if (canDelete) {

        checkIfLocked();

        if(!editable) {
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
        }

        return;
    }

    if (newDoc) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    }

    if (getSetting().isExcludedFromDeploy()) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_READ_ONLY_DOCUMENT);
    }

    checkIfLocked();

    // Default Message:
    throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
}
```

In my case if `canDelete` is true, then I have to call `checkIFLocked` and `throw exception` if not editable.

Here I think that I have a duplicate code witch is throwing the same exception, or I did called the same method twice in the same method block, which is `checkIfLocked`.

So is there any way to enhance this code block? Do I need to call the same method twice in the same method block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that `checkIfLocked()` returns `void`, and throws a `BusinessException` if the document is locked.

There is one way to succeed, and many ways to fail.  I think it would be beneficial to rearrange the code to make it obvious what the criteria for success are:

```
public void checkIfCanDelete() throws BusinessException {
    if (editable && canDelete()) {
        checkIfLocked();
        return;  // Can delete
    }

    // Can't delete.  We just have to choose a reason for the denial.
    if (canDelete()) {
        assert !editable;
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
    } else if (newDoc) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    } else if (getSetting().isExcludedFromDeploy()) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_READ_ONLY_DOCUMENT);
    }
    checkIfLocked();
    throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
}
```

The code above preserves the same logic as the original.  However, if you're not picky about which reason you pick for the denial, you could simplify the code further:

```
public void checkIfCanDelete() throws BusinessException {
    checkIfLocked();

    if (!(editable && canDelete())) {
        throw new BusinessException(
            newDoc ?
                BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_NEW_DOCUMENT :
            getSetting().isExcludedFromDeploy() ?
                BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_READ_ONLY_DOCUMENT :
                BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS;
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree, with Malachi by moving the variable to the `if` statement, since its not being used anywhere else.

If they are both performing a `checkIfLocked()` on the file, wouldn't it be better to perform this first, then continue one with the other checks?

```
    public void checkIfCanDelete() throws BusinessException {

      checkIfLocked();

      if (canDelete()) {
        if(!editable) {
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
        }
        return;
      }

      if (newDoc) {
          throw new BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_NEW_DOCUMENT);
      } else if (getSetting().isExcludedFromDeploy()) {
          throw new  BusinessException(BusinessException.MSG_DOCUMENT_CANNOT_DELETE_A_READ_ONLY_DOCUMENT);
      }

      // Default Message:
      throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
    }
```

Comment: Updated the code by remove the 2 elses

Answer (score 3):

right here:

```
boolean canDelete = canDelete();

if (canDelete) {

    checkIfLocked();

    if(!editable) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
    }

    return;
}
```

you can remove the Boolean variable and code it like this

```
if (canDelete()) {
    checkIfLocked();
    if(!editable) {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessError.MSG_YOU_ARE_NOT_AUTHORIZED_TO_REMOVE_DOCUMENTS);
    }
    return;
}
```

if the return value of the function is a `boolean` you should be able to just call the function inside the expression of the if statement.

that is the only thing that I could see.

I don't know what `checkIfLocked()` does,  it would be nice to see that as well.

---

I don't know what all `checkIfLocked()` and `canDelete()` do, but I would imagine that you should just have `checkIfLocked()` inside of your `canDelete()` function and eliminate the call to it from this `checkIfCanDelete()` Method.

**If it's locked you can't delete it right?**